# CSS style theming for checkboxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the picture above on the Target Time section....

All I have is as below... But the placement is not right when I resize my browser, and I don't know how to add the peak time picture above the checkboxes. Anyone can help ?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <label style="float:left; margin-right:14px;">Target Time</label>
    <div style="float:left; display:block;">
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="7am-11:59am" name="target_time[]" />7am-11:59am</label>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="12pm-5:59pm" name="target_time[]" />12pm-5:59pm</label>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="6pm-9:59pm" name="target_time[]" />6pm-9:59pm</label>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative; display:block;">
        <div style="float: left; border-right: 1px solid #aaa; height: 5em;"></div>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="10:00pm-2:00am" name="target_time[]" />10:00pm-2:00am</label>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="2:01am-6:59am" name="target_time[]" />2:01am-6:59am</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/a8VpS/1/

Comment: What is not right on resize? What do you expect?

Comment: When I make my browser smaller, the checkboxes and the line are out of place... The bottom 2 checkboxes should be align with the top one and the line would disappear or go to bottom line when my windows is re-sized smaller....

Comment: Do you have a link to the page? Or can you create a jsfiddle to illustrate? It seems you are using Twitter Bootstrap. Why the floating DIVs? Did you copy the code from somewhere?

Comment: It's a theme that I purchase called "Gebo" and I'm trying to modify to make it look the way I wanted. Will try to create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this kind of structure.if yes then check the following structure for you check boxes

```
    <div  style="float:left;">
        <img src='http://forums.animesuki.com/images/as.global/icons/icon7.gif'><br>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="7am-11:59am" name="target_time[]"/>7am-11:59am
        </label>
    </div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/7w8TC/10/)

Is this what you expect -->
[Check The updated Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/a8VpS/2/)

Comment: It's almost what I want, but I dont mean that I need to click the checkbox for the image to appear. I need it to be there always. Excactly like the picture I put above on my first post